# How can I repeatedly call my function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function in Matlab and call it repeatedly.
this is my code:

```
function T=FirstTemperature()
clc
T=0.8;

 randVariable=10*rand(1,2);
 ErandVariable=Objectivef(randVariable(1),randVariable(2));

 present=randVariable;
 Epresent=ErandVariable;

DEpositive=0;
positive=0;%for counting DeltaEpositive



 for i=1:10

 randVariable=10*rand(1,2);
 ErandVariable =Objectivef(randVariable(1),randVariable(2));

 DE=(ErandVariable-Epresent);

 if(DE<0)
    present=randVariable;
    Epresent=ErandVariable;
  %  disp('i move there')

 else
    DEpositive=DE+DEpositive;
    positive=positive+1;%for counting

    P=exp(- (DE)/ (2.038*T));
    a=rand(1);

    if(P>a)
       present=randVariable;
       Epresent=ErandVariable;
       %disp('with A probability i accepted')
    end

 end



end

  x0=0.9;
averag=DEpositive/positive;%average of deltapositive
T=averag/log(x0);

end
```

and I call this function repeatedly in a script file , in this way:

```
for k=1:10
disp('Hello')


T=FirstTemperature()
```

end

I want to display "Hello" for being aware of how does it run. this is the output:

```
Hello

T =

 -135.9965

>>
```

So,my code runs just one time instead of repeatting 10 time,What can I do ?

Comment: Looks like you need a semicolon after disp('Hello')

Comment: @JeremyKahan No,I run this code without the function & it showed 'Hello ',10 times

Comment: And if you remove disp('Hello') you still get jut one temperature?

Comment: @JeremyKahanYes,but my function should everytime show another temperature,because I use rand() in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function calls [`clc`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clc.html), which clears the screen. The function does run 10 times, but you only see the output of the last time.

Comment: No this is not the reason,I called it in the first line and I use a loop after it,I runned my code without that 'clc' and no difference was occured.

Comment: Try removing `clc` - it works. You call it in the first line of the *function*. This entire function, everything between `function T=FirstTemperature()` and the last `end`, is run 10x by the loop.